# How to generate new delay for setInterval every call?

Tags: javascript

Hello so i am wonering how i can archive delays in setInterval?
Lets say i have something like this:

```js
function delay(min, max) {
   const d = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
   return d;
}


setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
}, delay(1000, 2000));
```

The problem here is, that it console log, all the time with generated delay. And i want to generate new delay every console.log. Is it possible?

Comment: You **are** generating new delay every call to `setInterval()`.  You just calling it 1 time.

Comment: setInterval is usually done at a predetermined interval. You would probably want to use setTimeout, and create that in a loop with a random timeout each time

Comment: @PM77-1 It's obvious what the OP is trying to do; he's trying to variate the delay each time the setInterval callback is called.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - no it's not since he does not specify what should trigger them and when they should stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` and call it recursivly:

```js
function delay(min, max) {
  const d = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  return d;
}

function func() {
  console.log("Hello");
  setTimeout(func, delay(1000, 2000));
}

setTimeout(func, delay(1000, 2000));
```

A more general way would be your own interval generator:

```js
function setVariableInterval(f, d) {

  function timeoutFunc() {
    f();
    setTimeout(timeoutFunc, d());
  }

  setTimeout(timeoutFunc, d());
}

//You would call it like:

setVariableInterval(func, delay.bind(null, 1000, 2000));
```

Comment: Hm... nice solution. :) I'll give it a shoot